# Execution failed for task ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets'. in expo

Tags: expo, android-build, eas

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

[stderr]

1: Task failed with an exception.

[stderr]

---

[stderr]

- What went wrong:

[stderr]

Execution failed for task ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.

[stderr]

> Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

[stderr]

- Try:

[stderr]

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

[stderr]

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[stderr]

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

[stderr]

==============================================================================

[stderr]

2: Task failed with an exception.

[stderr]

---

[stderr]

- What went wrong:

[stderr]

java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

[stderr]

- Try:

[stderr]

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

[stderr]

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[stderr]

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

[stderr]

==============================================================================

[stderr]

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

This error occurs and cannot be resolved.

I tried npm update but it doesn't work. Currently using macos and proceeding in expo environment. The above error occurs when using an easy build. What should I do?

and

Is the error as below related to the error above?

Error: Unable to resolve module /Users/iseungjun/Desktop/개발/gym/src/images/alarm-clock.png from /home/expo/workingdir/build/src/screens/MyReservationScreen.tsx:

None of these files exist:

- alarm-clock.png
- ../../../../Users/iseungjun/Desktop/개발/gym/src/images/alarm-clock.png/index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)

225 |     <View style={{flex:1.5,backgroundColor:'white',borderTopRightRadius:15,borderBottomRightRadius:15,alignItems:'center'}}>

226 |       <Image

> 227 |       source={require('/Users/iseungjun/Desktop/개발/gym/src/images/alarm-clock.png')}

```
  |                        ^
```

228 |       style={{width:'40%',height:'20%',top:'10%'}}

229 |       />

230 |

```
at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:137:15)

at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:260:43)

at Object.resolve (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:177:21)

at Graph._resolveDependencies (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:432:35)

at Graph._processModule (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:218:38)

at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)

at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

at async Graph._addDependency (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:314:20)

at async Promise.all (index 12)

at async Graph._processModule (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:263:5)
```

[stderr]

error Unable to resolve module /Users/iseungjun/Desktop/개발/gym/src/images/alarm-clock.png from /home/expo/workingdir/build/src/screens/MyReservationScreen.tsx:

[stderr]

None of these files exist:

[stderr]

- alarm-clock.png

[stderr]

- ../../../../Users/iseungjun/Desktop/개발/gym/src/images/alarm-clock.png/index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)

[stderr]

225 |     <View style={{flex:1.5,backgroundColor:'white',borderTopRightRadius:15,borderBottomRightRadius:15,alignItems:'center'}}>

[stderr]

226 |       <Image

[stderr]

> 227 |       source={require('/Users/iseungjun/Desktop/개발/gym/src/images/alarm-clock.png')}

[stderr]

```
  |                        ^
```

[stderr]

228 |       style={{width:'40%',height:'20%',top:'10%'}}

[stderr]

229 |       />

[stderr]

230 |

> Task :iamport-react-native:compileReleaseKotlin

> Task :react-native-seoul_kakao-login:compileReleaseKotlin

w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-seoul/kakao-login/android/src/main/java/com/dooboolab/kakaologins/RNKakaoLoginsModule.kt: (16, 27): Type mismatch: inferred type is Date? but Date was expected

w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-seoul/kakao-login/android/src/main/java/com/dooboolab/kakaologins/RNKakaoLoginsModule.kt: (95, 23): There is more than one label with such a name in this scope

w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-seoul/kakao-login/android/src/main/java/com/dooboolab/kakaologins/RNKakaoLoginsModule.kt: (100, 23): There is more than one label with such a name in this scope

w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-seoul/kakao-login/android/src/main/java/com/dooboolab/kakaologins/RNKakaoLoginsModule.kt: (103, 17): Condition 'token != null' is always 'true'

w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-seoul/kakao-login/android/src/main/java/com/dooboolab/kakaologins/RNKakaoLoginsModule.kt: (119, 23): There is more than one label with such a name in this scope

w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-seoul/kakao-login/android/src/main/java/com/dooboolab/kakaologins/RNKakaoLoginsModule.kt: (129, 23): There is more than one label with such a name in this scope

w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-seoul/kakao-login/android/src/main/java/com/dooboolab/kakaologins/RNKakaoLoginsModule.kt: (132, 13): The expression is unused

w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-seoul/kakao-login/android/src/main/java/com/dooboolab/kakaologins/RNKakaoLoginsModule.kt: (141, 23): There is more than one label with such a name in this scope

w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-seoul/kakao-login/android/src/main/java/com/dooboolab/kakaologins/RNKakaoLoginsModule.kt: (144, 13): The expression is unused

w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-seoul/kakao-login/android/src/main/java/com/dooboolab/kakaologins/RNKakaoLoginsModule.kt: (189, 53): Unnecessary non-null assertion (!!) on a non-null receiver of type Account

w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-seoul/kakao-login/android/src/main/java/com/dooboolab/kakaologins/RNKakaoLoginsModule.kt: (195, 56): Unnecessary non-null assertion (!!) on a non-null receiver of type Account

w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-seoul/kakao-login/android/src/main/java/com/dooboolab/kakaologins/RNKakaoLoginsModule.kt: (225, 23): There is more than one label with such a name in this scope

w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-seoul/kakao-login/android/src/main/java/com/dooboolab/kakaologins/RNKakaoLoginsModule.kt: (261, 23): There is more than one label with such a name in this scope

> Task :expo-modules-core:compileReleaseKotlin

w: Argument -Xopt-in is deprecated. Please use -opt-in instead

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/adapters/react/permissions/PermissionsService.kt:157:30 'getPackageInfo(String, Int): PackageInfo!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/core/utilities/EmulatorUtilities.kt:30:13 'SERIAL: String!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/Promise.kt:68:18 This declaration overrides deprecated member but not marked as deprecated itself. This deprecation won't be inherited in future releases. Please add @Deprecated annotation or suppress. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-47902 for details

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/activityresult/ActivityResultsManager.kt:52:24 Parameter 'activity' is never used

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/activityresult/AppContextActivityResultRegistry.kt:119:51 'getParcelableExtra(String!): T?' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/activityresult/AppContextActivityResultRegistry.kt:180:26 'getParcelable(String?): T?' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/activityresult/AppContextActivityResultRegistry.kt:271:83 'getParcelable(String?): T?' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/activityresult/DataPersistor.kt:67:20 'getSerializable(String?): Serializable?' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/activityresult/DataPersistor.kt:85:26 'getSerializable(String?): Serializable?' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/events/KModuleEventEmitterWrapper.kt:90:7 'constructor Event<T : Event<(raw) Event<*>>!>(Int)' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/jni/JavaScriptObject.kt:59:33 Parameter 'null' is never used

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/jni/JavaScriptObject.kt:100:5 Parameter 'null' is never used

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/modules/Module.kt:43:7 'coroutineScope: CoroutineScope' is deprecated. Use a scope from the AppContext

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/types/Either.kt:24:11 Parameter 'type' is never used

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/types/Either.kt:27:11 Parameter 'type' is never used

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/types/Either.kt:44:11 Parameter 'type' is never used

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/types/Either.kt:59:11 Parameter 'type' is never used

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/types/JSTypeConverterHelper.kt:44:17 'get(String!): Any?' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/views/ViewManagerDefinitionBuilder.kt:125:30 'ViewGroupDefinitionLegacyBuilder' is deprecated. Use `ViewGroupDefinitionBuilder` instead.

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/views/ViewManagerDefinitionBuilder.kt:128:38 'ViewGroupDefinitionLegacyBuilder' is deprecated. Use `ViewGroupDefinitionBuilder` instead.

w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build/kotlin/sessions

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

[stderr]

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).